# Is it possible to bottom align images and top align a caption beneath them?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, vertical-alignment

I need to arrange a dynamic number of images in a Zurb Foundation [Block Grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html) and each image has a caption of a varying length.

I was wondering if there is any way to align everything so:

[image: Image Diagram]

I have been able to bottom align everything: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waffl/hnNy5/6/embedded/result/)

```
ul.block-grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

ul.block-grid li img {
    vertical-align: baseline;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

But am unable to figure out how to achieve the alignment I would like. I have tried absolute positioning the captions, but then they lose their width and height (and position in the DOM of course): [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waffl/hnNy5/7/embedded/result/)

```
ul.block-grid li p.caption {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Any tips for achieving this alignment greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't think you can with this HTML setup.

Comment: Not even with javascript?

Comment: Yeah probably.. didn't know you wanted a solution with that, you should tag JavaScript in your question.

Comment: You are really quite close with your absolute positioning.  You only need to define an element for the absolute positioning to be relative to.  The absolute positioning taking your captions way out of position is because they are being positioned relative to the body element.  Adding position: relative; to something like the LI will tell the captions to position themselves relative to the LI, effectively limiting the area they position themselves in.

Comment: I would have also thought that something as simple as setting a fixed height to the caption would work but I'm having trouble with that as well: http://jsfiddle.net/waffl/hnNy5/10/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also realize this layout using **CSS tables** as follows.

If the **HTML** looks like this:

```
<div class="row full-width">
    <div class="columns small-12">
        <ul class="block-grid small-block-grid-5">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400" />
                    <p class="caption">Test caption</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400" />
                    <p class="caption">A longer test caption...</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

apply the following **CSS**:

```css
.row.full-width {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: initial;
}
ul.block-grid li {
    display: inline-table;
    float: none;
}
ul.block-grid li a {
}
ul.block-grid li img {
    vertical-align: baseline;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
ul.block-grid li p.caption {
    text-align: center;
}
```

You have good enough semantic HTML so plenty of elements to work with.

Within the `.block-grid` containing block, set `display: inline-table` on the `li` element.

You can set `vertical-align` value to either `baseline` or `bottom` and then adjust margins and padding on the child elements as needed.

This CSS seems to work well with the Zurb Foundation classes.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/H5RLG/

**Design Comment:** If you have an overly long caption, then there will be extra large whitespace regions between any two rows of items, but you could always add a max-height to `p.caption` and enable vertical scrolling.  Alternatively, use JavaScript/jQuery and have an expandable panel with a "Show More" button.

In Firefox, the resulting layout looks like:

[image]

Comment: This works very well! Out of curiosity, is there any reason other than old IE support **not** to use table-rows? (akin to the negativity towards using HTML tables for layout?) Is there any way to center text in a `table-row`?

Comment: CSS tables (using the display property) is very well supported by most modern browsers. Your HTML retains the semantics of your original markup, which is good, and through CSS, you get more control in how the layout is visually rendered, all perfectly acceptable.  The negativity about tables harks back to the days when layouts consisted of nested tables (using table, tr, td and so on) with spacer GIF's, but we are well past that era of web development.

Comment: Great thank you, was just wondering about the last part of my comment, is there a way to center text in a `table-row` item?

Comment: Yes that's correct. It only centers the text if it is longer than one line for some reason.

Comment: @waffl I posted a variation that addresses centering the text within `p.caption`.

Comment: You could also work around the centering problem by wrapping `p.caption` in a block element that uses `display: table-row`, but this is not strictly necessary.

Comment: @waffl I misread your HTML and just noticed that the `a` element encloses both the image and the paragraph.  In this case, the solution is even simpler, no need for table-row's or a nested inline-table.  Please see updated solution.

Answer (score 4):

It can be achieved with absolute positioning.  The catch here is variable heights on your captions...  You need to apply appropriate bottom margin to the containing row element, or else the captions will overlap anything beneath them.

[**JS Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hnNy5/9/)

*Only the following selectors were changed...*

```
ul.block-grid li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

ul.block-grid li a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
```

To answer your sort of secondary issue about trying absolute positioning and the text losing it's position.  The reason the absolute positioning works in my example is because I set the `<li>` element to `position: relative;`  This means any children of the LI that has absolute positioning, will be positioned relative to the `<li>` and not relative to the `<body>`.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I agreed to the other answer because it allowed me to avoid having to set a margin/height to avoid overlap.

Comment: @waffl It is the better answer certainly, I only posted this to show you that you were close with what you were attempting.